# Custom mfc MDI child window title bar drawing (variable thickness)

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, mfc, titlebar, mdichild

I have a MDI project. Multiple child windows are created. I want to customize the frame of the child windows. The title bar thickness needs to be reduced. I tried to handle ON_WM_NCPAINT()
ON_WM_CREATE()
It hasnt worked. Need some help in custom drawing of the title bar.
Any help would be appreciated. Any link for sample project would be helpful.
Thanks & Regards,
Rakesh

What I have tried:

I have tried handling

```
ON_WM_NCPAINT()
ON_WM_CREATE()
ON_WM_SIZE()
ON_WM_PAINT()
```

I didnt see the title bar change in any way. Probably I am not doing it rightly.

Comment: Sounds like there is a bug in your code. But since we cannot see it, you can't expect to get much help. Please show a [mcve].

Comment: I think I dont know how to do change the title bar thickness. On my part I tried to add a handler OnNcPaint into the ChildFrame.cpp. I tried to paint a region but the paintin never showed. Some steps on how to achieve this would be good.

Comment: You need to handle [`WM_NCCALCSIZE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632634.aspx)